# Libgdx create sequence action programmatically

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

In my libGDX application I have an actor which needs to create actions programmatically.

At the minute I am adding moveBy actions with incrementing delays in order to get the desired effect but this is very inefficient. Something like below;

```
actor.addAction(sequence(delay(i * DELAY), moveBy(50, 50));
```

If possible I would like to programmatically create one single sequence action and add moveBy actions to it as needed. Then I could just invoke a single action without having to continually add actions which is very unresourceful.

I have checked the documentation and could not find anything specific to my particular need.

I was thinking something along the lines of (pseudo code);

```
addPath(Vector2 path) {

    paths.add(path);
}

invokePathAction() {

    Action sequence = sequence();
    for all paths
        sequence.add(moveBy(path.x, path.y, TIME));

    addAction(sequence);
}
```

Is something like this possible with libGDX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course - there is **addAction** method in the [SequenceAction](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/actions/SequenceAction.html) class

```
    MoveToAction action1 = new MoveToAction();
    action1.setPosition(0, 0);
    action1.setDuration(2);

    MoveToAction action2 = new MoveToAction();
    action2.setPosition(-500, 0);
    action2.setDuration(2);

    ...

    SequenceAction sequence = new SequenceAction();

    sequence.addAction(action1);
    sequence.addAction(action2);

    ...

    actor.addAction(sequence);
```

if you want to clear all actions and have "empty" sequence again you can call

```
    sequence.reset();
```

Comment: Don't know how I missed this! Embarrassing to say the least!

Comment: All in all these are inherited methods :)

Comment: Ye, when I tried first time round I was doing `Action action = sequence();` hence not seeing the `addAction` as I wasn't typecasting properly! Thanks again :)